Error: transaction execution reverted in SimpleAccount Contract worldchain
When I try to perform a transaction with my contract for Account Abstraction, I get an transaction execution reverted error
Connected to network: Network {}
Master wallet: 0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776
User wallet: 0xD6C7481C875fBb69a07eC4e39Df6c690ABC69568
Initializing SimpleAccount through EntryPoint...
Initialization error: Error: transaction execution reverted (action="sendTransaction", data=null, reason=null, invocation=null, revert=null, transaction={ "data": "", "from": "0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776", "to": "0xe9eF1039E7781248aEfaEDA5a1650260dE1EaFf5" }, receipt={ "_type": "TransactionReceipt", "blobGasPrice": null, "blobGasUsed": null, "blockHash": "0x4ffdfdb90cb4f9a4dc5cdc56efdec657bb2d7a9fd253dbdca19637d2c78f67d8", "blockNumber": 6142023, "contractAddress": null, "cumulativeGasUsed": "70059", "from": "0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776", "gasPrice": "100263", "gasUsed": "26208", "hash": "0x5d41d4f6783796931031e856e7f541b897e949ac203839183c6e0edee23ee3aa", "index": 1, "logs": [  ], "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "root": null, "status": 0, "to": "0xe9eF1039E7781248aEfaEDA5a1650260dE1EaFf5" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.4)
    at makeError (file:///home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/errors.js:124:21)
    at assert (file:///home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils/errors.js:143:15)
    at checkReceipt (file:///home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/providers/provider.js:1119:13)
    at JsonRpcProvider.txListener (file:///home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/providers/provider.js:1165:33)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'sendTransaction',
  data: null,
  reason: null,
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  transaction: {
    to: '0xe9eF1039E7781248aEfaEDA5a1650260dE1EaFf5',
    from: '0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776',
    data: ''
  },
  receipt: TransactionReceipt {
    provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
    to: '0xe9eF1039E7781248aEfaEDA5a1650260dE1EaFf5',
    from: '0x54c5c9FbFe99a6282dE10201b1c3254EAe8C9776',
    contractAddress: null,
    hash: '0x5d41d4f6783796931031e856e7f541b897e949ac203839183c6e0edee23ee3aa',
    index: 1,
    blockHash: '0x4ffdfdb90cb4f9a4dc5cdc56efdec657bb2d7a9fd253dbdca19637d2c78f67d8',
    blockNumber: 6142023,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    gasUsed: 26208n,
    blobGasUsed: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 70059n,
    gasPrice: 100263n,
    blobGasPrice: null,
    type: 2,
    status: 0,
    root: undefined
  },
  shortMessage: 'transaction execution reverted'
}
SimpleAccount owner: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Error detallado: Error: User wallet is not the owner of SimpleAccount
    at WorldChain.transfer (file:///home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/src/services/WorldChain1.js:115:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async file:///home/th3dgd/Dev/worldcoin-to-ars/nodo/index.js:30:26

This is the code that initializes SimpleAccount and also handles the transfer:
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const wldAbi = [
    "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public returns (bool)",
    "function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256)"
];

const simpleAccountAbi = [
    "function execute(address dest, uint256 value, bytes calldata func) external",
    "function initialize(address owner) public",
    "function entryPoint() external view returns (address)",
    "function owner() external view returns (address)"
];

const entryPointAbi = [
    "function handleOps((address sender, uint256 nonce, bytes initCode, bytes callData, uint256 callGasLimit, uint256 verificationGasLimit, uint256 preVerificationGas, uint256 maxFeePerGas, uint256 maxPriorityFeePerGas, bytes paymasterAndData, bytes signature)[] calldata ops, address beneficiary) external payable",
    "function getNonce(address sender, uint192 key) external view returns (uint256)"
];

const wldContractAddress = '0x2cFc85d8E48F8EAB294be644d9E25C3030863003';
const simpleAccountAddress = '0x765a4C783CA82FCb180F8a317B75D1C85e695a81';
const entryPointAddress = '0xe9eF1039E7781248aEfaEDA5a1650260dE1EaFf5';

class WorldChain {
    async initialize(privateKeyForGas, privateKeyForWLD) {
        try {
            const RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL;
            const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            const masterWallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForGas, provider);
            const userWallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForWLD, provider);
            
            const simpleAccount = new ethers.Contract(
                simpleAccountAddress,
                simpleAccountAbi,
                provider
            );
            
            const currentOwner = await simpleAccount.owner();
            if (currentOwner === ethers.ZeroAddress) {
                console.log('Initializing SimpleAccount through EntryPoint...');
                
                const initData = simpleAccount.interface.encodeFunctionData('initialize', [
                    userWallet.address
                ]);

                const entryPoint = new ethers.Contract(
                    entryPointAddress,
                    entryPointAbi,
                    masterWallet
                );

                const nonce = await entryPoint.getNonce(simpleAccountAddress, 0);

                const userOp = {
                    sender: simpleAccountAddress,
                    nonce: nonce,
                    initCode: '0x',
                    callData: initData,
                    callGasLimit: 500000,
                    verificationGasLimit: 500000,
                    preVerificationGas: 50000,
                    maxFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('20', 'gwei'),
                    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('2', 'gwei'),
                    paymasterAndData: '0x'
                };

                const userOpHash = await this._calculateUserOpHash(userOp, entryPointAddress, await provider.getNetwork());
                const signature = await this._signUserOp(userOpHash, userWallet);
                userOp.signature = signature;

                const tx = await entryPoint.handleOps([userOp], masterWallet.address, {
                    gasLimit: 1000000,
                    maxFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('20', 'gwei'),
                    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('2', 'gwei')
                });

                await tx.wait();
                console.log('SimpleAccount initialized successfully');
            }
            
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Initialization error:', error);
            return false;
        }
    }

    async transfer(toAddress, amount, privateKeyForGas, privateKeyForWLD) {
        try {
            const RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL;
            const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);

            const masterWallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForGas, provider);
            const userWallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyForWLD, provider);

            console.log('Connected to network:', await provider.getNetwork());
            console.log('Master wallet:', masterWallet.address);
            console.log('User wallet:', userWallet.address);

            await this.initialize(privateKeyForGas, privateKeyForWLD);

            const simpleAccount = new ethers.Contract(
                simpleAccountAddress,
                simpleAccountAbi,
                provider
            );
            
            const currentOwner = await simpleAccount.owner();
            console.log('SimpleAccount owner:', currentOwner);
            
            if (currentOwner.toLowerCase() !== userWallet.address.toLowerCase()) {
                throw new Error('User wallet is not the owner of SimpleAccount');
            }

            const wldToken = new ethers.Contract(wldContractAddress, wldAbi, provider);
            const wldBalance = await wldToken.balanceOf(simpleAccountAddress);
            console.log('WLD Balance:', ethers.formatEther(wldBalance));
            
            const amountInWei = ethers.parseUnits(amount.toString(), 18);
            console.log('Transfer amount:', ethers.formatEther(amountInWei));
            
            if (wldBalance < amountInWei) {
                throw new Error('Insufficient WLD balance');
            }

            const transferData = wldToken.interface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [
                toAddress,
                amountInWei
            ]);

            const executeData = simpleAccount.interface.encodeFunctionData('execute', [
                wldContractAddress,
                0,
                transferData
            ]);

            const entryPoint = new ethers.Contract(
                entryPointAddress,
                entryPointAbi,
                masterWallet
            );

            const nonce = await entryPoint.getNonce(simpleAccountAddress, 0);

            const userOp = {
                sender: simpleAccountAddress,
                nonce: nonce,
                initCode: '0x',
                callData: executeData,
                callGasLimit: 500000,
                verificationGasLimit: 500000,
                preVerificationGas: 50000,
                maxFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('20', 'gwei'),
                maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('2', 'gwei'),
                paymasterAndData: '0x'
            };

            const userOpHash = await this._calculateUserOpHash(userOp, entryPointAddress, await provider.getNetwork());
            const signature = await this._signUserOp(userOpHash, userWallet);
            userOp.signature = signature;

            const tx = await entryPoint.handleOps([userOp], masterWallet.address, {
                gasLimit: 1000000,
                maxFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('20', 'gwei'),
                maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.parseUnits('2', 'gwei')
            });

            const receipt = await tx.wait();
            
            return {
                status: 'success',
                receipt: receipt,
                details: {
                    hash: receipt.hash,
                    blockNumber: receipt.blockNumber,
                    gasUsed: receipt.gasUsed.toString()
                }
            };

        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error detallado:", error);
            return {
                status: 'error',
                error: error.message,
                details: {
                    code: error.code,
                    data: error.data,
                    reason: error.reason
                }
            };
        }
    }

    async _calculateUserOpHash(userOp, entryPointAddress, network) {
        const packed = ethers.solidityPacked(
            ['address', 'uint256', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'bytes32'],
            [
                userOp.sender,
                userOp.nonce,
                ethers.keccak256(userOp.initCode || '0x'),
                ethers.keccak256(userOp.callData),
                userOp.callGasLimit,
                userOp.verificationGasLimit,
                userOp.preVerificationGas,
                userOp.maxFeePerGas,
                userOp.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
                ethers.keccak256(userOp.paymasterAndData || '0x')
            ]
        );

        const enc = ethers.solidityPacked(
            ['bytes2', 'address', 'uint256', 'bytes32'],
            ['0x1900', entryPointAddress, network.chainId, ethers.keccak256(packed)]
        );

        return ethers.keccak256(enc);
    }

    async _signUserOp(userOpHash, wallet) {
        return await wallet.signMessage(ethers.getBytes(userOpHash));
    }
}

export default new WorldChain();

This is the contract code and the tests:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";
import "@account-abstraction/contracts/core/BaseAccount.sol";
import "@account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IEntryPoint.sol";
import "@account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/PackedUserOperation.sol";

contract SimpleAccount is BaseAccount {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    address public owner;
    IEntryPoint private immutable _entryPoint;
    uint256 constant SIG_VALIDATION_FAILED = 1;

    event SimpleAccountInitialized(IEntryPoint indexed entryPoint, address indexed owner);

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor(IEntryPoint anEntryPoint) {
        _entryPoint = anEntryPoint;
    }

    function initialize(address anOwner) public virtual {
        require(owner == address(0), "Already initialized");
        owner = anOwner;
        emit SimpleAccountInitialized(_entryPoint, owner);
    }

    function entryPoint() public view virtual override returns (IEntryPoint) {
        return _entryPoint;
    }

    // identifitier not found or not unique (UserOperation)
    function _validateSignature(PackedUserOperation calldata userOp, bytes32 userOpHash)
        internal virtual override returns (uint256 validationData) {
        bytes32 hash = MessageHashUtils.toEthSignedMessageHash(userOpHash);
        if (owner != hash.recover(userOp.signature))
            return SIG_VALIDATION_FAILED;
        return 0;
    }

    function execute(address dest, uint256 value, bytes calldata func) external {
        _requireFromEntryPointOrOwner();
        _call(dest, value, func);
    }

    function executeBatch(address[] calldata dest, bytes[] calldata func) external {
        _requireFromEntryPointOrOwner();
        require(dest.length == func.length, "Invalid array lengths");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < dest.length; i++) {
            _call(dest[i], 0, func[i]);
        }
    }

    function _requireFromEntryPointOrOwner() internal view {
        require(msg.sender == address(entryPoint()) || msg.sender == owner, "Account: not Owner or EntryPoint");
    }

    function _call(address target, uint256 value, bytes memory data) internal {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = target.call{value: value}(data);
        if (!success) {
            assembly {
                revert(add(result, 32), mload(result))
            }
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}

Tests:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "../src/ERC4337.sol";
import "@account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IEntryPoint.sol";
import "@account-abstraction/contracts/core/EntryPoint.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MessageHashUtils.sol";

contract ERC4337Test is Test {
    SimpleAccount public account;
    EntryPoint public entryPoint;
    address public owner;
    uint256 public ownerKey;

    function setUp() public {
        (owner, ownerKey) = makeAddrAndKey("owner");
        
        entryPoint = new EntryPoint();
        
        account = new SimpleAccount(entryPoint);
        account.initialize(owner);

        vm.deal(address(account), 1 ether);
    }

    function testInitialization() public view {
        assertEq(account.owner(), owner);
        assertEq(address(account.entryPoint()), address(entryPoint));
    }

    function testExecute() public {
        address target = makeAddr("target");
        uint256 value = 0.1 ether;
        bytes memory data = "";

        vm.expectRevert("Account: not Owner or EntryPoint");
        account.execute(target, value, data);

        vm.prank(owner);
        account.execute(target, value, data);
    }

    function testValidateUserOp() public {
        PackedUserOperation memory userOp = PackedUserOperation({
            sender: address(account),
            nonce: 0,
            initCode: bytes(""),
            callData: bytes(""),
            accountGasLimits: bytes32(uint256(1000000))
            preVerificationGas: 1000000,
            gasFees: bytes32(uint256(1000000000))
            paymasterAndData: bytes(""),
            signature: bytes("")
        });

        bytes32 userOpHash = entryPoint.getUserOpHash(userOp);
        bytes32 hash = MessageHashUtils.toEthSignedMessageHash(userOpHash);

        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = vm.sign(ownerKey, hash);
        userOp.signature = abi.encodePacked(r, s, v);

        vm.prank(address(entryPoint));
        account.validateUserOp(userOp, userOpHash, 0);
    }


    function testExecuteBatch() public {
        address[] memory targets = new address[](2);
        targets[0] = makeAddr("target1");
        targets[1] = makeAddr("target2");

        bytes[] memory callData = new bytes[](2);
        callData[0] = "";
        callData[1] = "";

        vm.expectRevert("Account: not Owner or EntryPoint");
        account.executeBatch(targets, callData);

        vm.prank(owner);
        account.executeBatch(targets, callData);
    }
}

Finally, I am using the EntryPoint from OpenZeppelin, which I deployed on WorldChain using my private key
